# "table or view does not exist" Comming in Oracle DB

Tags: database, oracle, subquery

```
NAME    PAYMENT
James   1000    
Kepler  2000    
Ronny   1300    
Edward  1500    
Patrick 1700    
John    1660    
Danny   1600    
Hemry   1234    
Harry   1236
```

**select * from(
select * from student ) t1 where t1.payment=(select max(payment) from t1)**

*this is showing wrong*

**select * from student where payment=(select max(payment) from student)**

*this is corre*

But can anyone clarify why t1 is not correct? how to use t1 is where clause please tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This causing error because T1 is not a table , from should be precedent with a table, you can use Common Table Expression

for example

```
with ct as (
select 1,2 from dual )

select * from ct
```

in your example

```
with st as ( select * from student)
select * from st where st.paymnet=(select max(payment) from st)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with t1 as (select max(payment) payment from student )

select name, student.payment from student ,t1 where student.payment = t1.
```

Comment: haha littlefoot beat me to it, but like them; I too would use a CTE for this.

Answer (score 1):

CTE is maybe the simplest option; `T1` will be CTE itself, and you can then reference it afterwards:

```
with t1 as (select * from student)
select * from t1
where t1.payment = (select max(payment) from t1);
```